# FFT doesn't return correct amplitude

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to use simple FFT to make Fourier transform of some function, but apparently the `numpy` and `scipy` FFT doesn't work so well even for 1024 points.

For example, suppose I want to make FFT of `sin(50x)+cos(80x)`. Then, at `k=50` point should be purely imaginary and `k=80` should be purely real. Generally there is some error, but working with a number of points as large as 1024 generally gives quite satisfactory output. But here there is quite a bit of error in the output. The result doesn't improve much with increasing number of points.

Can someone explain the reason of this?

I have tried the following code in Python:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack

pi = np.pi

#no. of points
N = 1024

#real axis
x = np.linspace(0,2*pi,N)

#real fn
f_x = np.sin(50*x)+np.cos(80*x)

f_k = (2/N)*scipy.fftpack.fft(f_x)

print f_k[50]
print f_k[80]
```

and it gives the following output:

```
(0.155273271152-0.983403030451j)
(0.960302223459+0.242617561413j)
```

which should have been, `0-1j` and `1+0j`. With 1024 points I was expecting a more accurate result.

I have also tried transforming by using explicit FT formula, and `numpy` instead of `scipy`. Both give the same accuracy.

Comment: The fft functions calculate the *discrete* fourier transform, and do so exactly, up to floating point precision. The discrete transform is however not the same thing as the continuous transform.

Comment: But, here, as the given functions are periodic, sin(50x)+cos(80x), discrete fourier transform is what we need right?

Comment: What you need depends on what you are trying to do; what you write above sounds like you expect discrete transform behave similarly as the continuous one. In particular, for the discrete transform the precise way sampling is done matters, as pointed out in the answers below. For example, try `x = np.linspace(0,2*pi,N+1)[:-1]`. Please see course materials for signal processing courses for more details.

Answer (score 2):

For ideal, infinite-length signals it would be `0-1j` and `1+0j`.  However, this is a finite-length, digital signal.  Due to windowing and the limitations in representing floating-point numbers on a computer, it is never going to perfectly match the ideal case.

Comment: But in may other places in computation we get quite satisfactory results, that is what is bothering me here. Why is the result so poor in this case inspite of using a 1024 length? Also, the accuracy doesn't converge so fast if we incerase the number of points.

Answer (score -1):

Your input length looks like it is off by one.

An FFT only give exact results for sinusoids that exactly integer periodic in the FFT length.  For the infinitely many other frequencies, you can improve the results by parabolic or Sinc interpolation between FFT result bins.

Comment: It isn't off by one.  The code is all there.  I tried re-running his code with lengths of 1023 and 1025 and it still had the same effect.

Comment: But these ARE sinusoidals with periods of 50 and 80.